# How to create a Flip control in WPF 4?

Tags: c#, wpf, animation, wpf-4.0

I am a Silverlight developer and in Silverlight we made use of PlanarProjection to create such effects. Infact this is the article along with demo project in Silverlight by Mike Taulty:

http://mtaulty.com/CommunityServer/blogs/mike_taultys_blog/archive/2009/04/27/silverlight-3-simple-flip-control-built-on-planeprojection.aspx

How can we make such a realistic control in WPF because there is no PlanarProjection (2.5D) in WPF4. Can you provide me any code or guideline or sample project along with source code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WPF lacks the `PlaneProjection` of Silverlight.  It's annoying that these incompatibilities exist, but admittedly the problem is usually Silverlight lacking a WPF feature.  So this time for WPF developers the shoe is on the other foot!

If what you want is `PlaneProjection`, here is an article that implements a feature with similar capabilities:

- PlaneProjection in WPF ([previously](http://blog.endquote.com/post/710116433/planeprojection-in-wpf), link is now dead)

which itself also references some other attempts.

But if what you want is a WPF dual-sided content control with flipping similar to the article you linked, you can use Josh Smith's `ContentControl3D`:

- [Introducing ContentControl3D](http://joshsmithonwpf.wordpress.com/2009/02/23/introducing-contentcontrol3d/)
- [Rotating WPF Content in 3D Space](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/ContentControl3D.aspx) (The Code Project)

This control can flip front and back content in a very configurable way.  I wouldn't be surprised if Mike Taulty's implementation was inspired by it.

Someday WPF may have `PlaneProjection` and then the same technique will work for both Silverlight and WPF.  Until then, you can easily adapt the simple `PlaneProjection` flipper to use the same API as `ContentControl3D` as a compromise.

Comment: wow, the PlaneProjection in WPF is just awesome. Don't know how do they write such code. These things are never taught in any book.

Comment: PlaneProjection linbk in WPF is dead.

Comment: Archive of PlaneProjection in WPF link https://web.archive.org/web/20120610195312/http://blog.endquote.com:80/post/710116433/planeprojection-in-wpf